# Module doesn't have member in JSII Python package

Tags: python, typescript, amazon-web-services, jsii

I am following [AWS User Guide](https://aws.github.io/jsii/user-guides/lib-author/quick-start/write-code/) to create a Python package from TypeScript Source via JSII. My TypeScript source looks like this:

```
export interface GreeterProps {
  readonly greetee: string;
}

export class Greeter {
  private readonly greetee: string;

  public constructor(props: GreeterProps) {
    this.greetee = props.greetee;
  }

  public greet(): string {
    return `Hello, ${this.greetee}!`
  }
}
```

This is section from JSII config for Python:

```
    "targets": {
      "python": {
        "distName": "jsii-test.jsii-test",
        "module": "jsii_test.jsii_test"
      }
    }
```

The project builds without errors and, and Python package is created successfully. I uploaded the package (via `twine`) to AWS CodeArtifact, and installed (via `pip`). When I import it in interactive Python console (`import jsii_test`) it imports successfully, but it doesn't seem to have the members exported from the original TypeScript source (GreeterProps, Greeter). What am I missing?

Project source: https://github.com/YuriGal/jsii-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out `pip` was installing package into incorrect location (I have to sort out my python versions). When I added path where the package was installed

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages')
```

everything worked.